# How to find the generic type of both Key/Value in IGrouping collection with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 based project that is written with c#. I've created a Razor helper that is called `@Html.DisplayTableFor(x => x.Records)` where `Records` implements `IEnumerable`.

The `DisplayTableFor` extension method will create an HTML table where each `record` in the `Records` collection represents a row (`<tr>...</tr>`) in the HTML table. It works great for me now when I just want to dump data into an HTML table. But, I like to expand it further so it can take grouped lists and render it also making a summary table look not just a raw data dump.

If for example, I have the following row data

```
Name        Salary  Department
John Doe    100000  IT
Jane Doe    75000   Sales
Jay T       50000   Sales
Jack S      60000   Sales
Mike S      65000   IT
Dave B      70000   IT
B Smith     80000   IT
```

Let's say I want to group the records by `Department` then by `Name`.I would want the `DisplayTableFor` method to generate something like this output in HTML table

[image]

Follow is my first approach to generate the summary-table. First I would inspect the generic type of the collection. If the generic type implements the `IGrouping` interface, then I would know that this collection is grouped and should be rendered as a summary table otherwise render the data as a data-dump format.

This is the model that represents each raw row.

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

public class RecordsKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I would create my groped collection.

```
var records = new List<Record>(){.. some records ...}
var grouped = records.GroupBy(x => new RecordsKey 
{
 Department = x.Department,
 Name = x.Name
}).ToList();
```

In my `DisplayTableFor` extension method, I execute the following code to find the `ModelMetadata` of the generic type (i.e. `IGouping<RecordsKey, Records>`)

```
Type type = TableHelpers.GetCollectionType(propertyMetadata.Model as IEnumerable);
if (type == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find the generic type");
}

ModelMetadata typeMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, type);

var columns = new Dictionary<string, TableDataColumn>();

foreach (ModelMetadata propertyMetadata in propertyMetadatas)
{
    // TODO... Execution steps
    // IF propertyMetadata.ModelType is assignable from IGrouping<>
    // 1) Find the generic type of the "IGrouping.Key" and foreach property on the Type create new TableDataColumn()
    // 2) Find the generic type of the "IGrouping.Value" and foreach property on the Type create a new TableDataColumn()
    // ELSE
    // columns.Add(new TableDataColumn(propertyMetadata));
    // ENDIF
}
```

However, I am unable to convert TODO steps above comments into valid c# code.

Question, how can I check if a type implements `IGrouping`? Also, how can I get the `ModelMetadata` of the `IGrouping.Key` and `IGrouping.Value`?

Comment: One way of checking if object x implements IGroup is to use the `is` key word which can be combined with some nice new c# features and an if statement like this `if (x is IGrouping grouping)` and within the scope of the if statement you can use the grouping variable which is of type IGrouping. If it isn't that type that will return false and you wont enter the if statement scope

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do with your  `.GroupBy(x => RecordsKey{ ... }` code - you just creating one record for each record in the original. Surely you want something like `.GroupBy(x => x.Department).Select(x => new ...`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke is I do Select() the records are no longer grouped. Then how could I access them using Key and Value? the point of using IGrouping here is to create a summary table. Perhaps I am missing the use of IGrouping

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. What you would have is another model - say `public class RecordsVM { public string Department { get; set }; public List<RecordsKey> Records { get; set; } };` (except that `RecordsKey` would contain `public double Salary { get; set; }`, not `public string Department { get; set; }`. Then the query would be `var grouped = records.GroupBy(x => x.Department).Select(x => new RecordsVM{ Department = x.Key, Records = x.Select(y => new RecordsKey{ Name = y.Name, Salary = y.Salary }).ToList() });`

Comment: Then it becomes easier in the extension method. You are passing a collection, so you can check if its `IEnumerable`, then loop each property and it one of the properties itself is `IEnumerable`, then you create your 'grouped' table as per your image

Comment: I would however consider a separate extension method for grouped data rather than trying to combine it all into one method - say `@Html.GroupedTableDisplayFor(m => m.yourCollectionProperty)`

Comment: The reason I was thinking about key/value pair is that the key would be different it could be string/int/double/object... which is why I was hoping to use more of a generic way to define grouped collection from the non-grouped collection and then render the results accordingly.

Comment: Yes but surely you want to create a view model for each 'table' that you want to display - and be able to add attributes for display/formatting etc (and what you are doing is not grouping anything anyway - if you have 10 records, then the result of `var grouped = ...` is also 10 records)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I agree with you That I should use .Select() after calling GroupBy. to select the result of the grouping. But instead of the viewModel, can't I use Dictionary<object, object> for my grouped results? If that is something you think would work, how would I figure out the Key/Value types and the ModelMetadata for both the key.. I am thinking something like Dictionary<RecordKey,List<Record>>()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181374/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mike-a).